# How to authenticate WEB API controller method using HMACSHA256

Tags: c#, authentication, webapi, hmacsha256

I am new to web API. I would appreciate if somebody could give me the sample code for authenticate a user by creating hash using HMACSHA256.Following is my API Controller code. I want `GetCategoryNewsByFilter` to be authenticated before calling it.

```
using NewsBytesApi.Attributes;
using NewsBytesApi.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace NewsBytesApi.Controllers
{

  
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        NewsLetterDBEntities dataContext = null;
       
   

        public List<storyRepo> GetCategoryNewsByFilter()
           {
    
               dataContext = new NewsLetterDBEntities();
               List<storyRepo> lstStoryRepo = new List<storyRepo>();
               storyRepo obj = new storyRepo();
               obj.StoryContent = "ABC";
               obj.StoryHeader = "DEF";
               lstStoryRepo.Add(obj);
               return lstStoryRepo;
    
           }
              
        }
    }
```

Comment: please add errors or additional details to highlight your exact question

Comment: Before calling the ValuesController,I want to Authenticate the user by comparing Hash. I have put RESTAuthorizeAttribute above ValuesController but it is not called before calling the method.

Comment: My requirement is to compare hash generated by HMACSHA256 at the client using a key to the hash generated by HMACSHA256 at the server by the same key before calling the GetCategoryNewsByFilter method inside the ValuesController. If hash is matched then only GetCategoryNewsByFilter  should be called otherwise it should give some message to the user.